# How to resolve the error "Unexpected Element: CDATA" while running test step thru groovy script?

Tags: java, testing, soap, groovy, soapui

I'm running test suite which contains 15 test steps mixed with groovy script and soap request steps.

It runs perfectly when I'm running manually where as its giving the error message like **"Unexpected Element: CDATA"** while executing thru the groovy script.

**Groovy Script:**

```
for(tc in testsuite.testCaseList)
{
   for(stp in tc.testStepList)
   {
      if (!stp.isDisabled())
      {
         testRunner.runTestStep(stp)

         def assertionList = stp.getAssertionList()
         ..........
      }
   }
}
```

**Get Response Data thru another groovy script step:**

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("requestName#Response")
def appId = responseHolder.getNodeValue("//*:application/*:applicationId")

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("AppId",appId)
```

Could anyone give me your suggestion to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: please edit your question and provide the value of `requestName#Response` and full error.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get the value of Application Id from the response. That is one of the tag in the response.

Comment: Ok. I believe problem is in response.

Comment: What shall I do if that issue belongs to the response. I'm able to get the "appid" when I ran that teststep manually. but only problem i'm facing this issue while running thru "groovy script" as I mentioned in post.

Comment: ask to fix the response if the problem in it.